# Outputting an array and it skips one element

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012

So I will be honest, I am very new to programming and I have read other boards that have this same topic and I am unable to find where I might be messing up.

For my program I am inputting a text file of a multiple choice quiz into two different arrays. One array holds the quiz questions and the multiple choice answers (so it is a 2D array), while the other array holds the answers. These are then outputted to the user and the user can take the quiz and then get the results of their quiz at the end.

So I've done probably the most basic debugging of stepping through my program and making sure that my file loaded into my arrays properly (which it did) so I don't think it's an issue with loading my file into the arrays, but how they're being outputted.

So what's my problem?

When I start to output my quiz and the user starts to take it the first question comes up fine (as well as the multiple choice answers) and the answer to it is correct, BUT when it moves on to the second question it skips and outputs the third question instead, but still outputs question 2's multiple choice answers, which throws the whole test off. So essentially it is outputting array[2][0] and then the rest of the elements in row 1, instead of array[ 1][0] and then the rest of the elements in row 1. So all the questions are off by one.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it's only skipping that one element of the array but reading out everything else just fine? Thank you for your help in advance!

Below is an example of what the text file looks like.

> An Integrated Development Environment typically consists of: 
>   A text editor 
>   A compiler 
>   A debugger 
>   All of the above 
>   None of the above 
>   D

And it goes on. There are 12 questions total in the file, no extra spaces between the lines.

Below is the loops for my codes, everything has been declared and initialized.

```
int countRow = 0;                   //Counter for the rows in the array
    int countCol = 0;               //Counter for the columns in the array
    const int ARRAY_ROW = 11;           //Rows in the array
    const int ARRAY_COL = 6;            //Columns in the array
    string line;                    //String variable to put into the array

    //Filling the 2D array and the answer array
    for (countRow = 0; countRow < ARRAY_ROW; countRow++)
    {
        for (countCol = 0; countCol < (ARRAY_COL); countCol++)
        {
            getline(inFile, line);
            testArr[countRow][countCol] = line;
        }

        //Filling the answer array
        if (countCol == 6)
        {
            getline(inFile, line);
            testAnswers[countRow] = line;
        }

    }


    string choice;              //Variable for user input
    string answer;              //Variable for the correct answer
    int rightAnswer = 0;        //Accumulator for the right answer
    int row = 0;                //Counter for rows
    int col = 0;                //Counter for columns
    int questionNum = 1;        //Number of the question
    char option = 'A';          //Lettering options for the user to choose from


    cout << "Select the appropriate option for your desired answer." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    for (row = 0; row < ARRAY_ROW; row++)
    {
        cout << "Question " << questionNum << ": " << testArr[row][col] << endl;
        cout << endl;
        questionNum++;

        for (col = 1, option = 'A'; col < ARRAY_COL, option < 'F'; col++, option++)
        {
            cout << option << " - " << testArr[row][col] << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
        answer = testAnswers[row];
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        if (choice == answer)
        {
            cout << "Correct, you chose the right answer: " << answer << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
            rightAnswer++;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Incorrect, the correct answer is: ";
            cout << answer << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your answers one word answers, or can they be more than one word?

Comment: @RSahu They are multi-word lines, but the answer is a single character, but I am reading it in as a string. (I will upload a pic of the text file for reference)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow.  You will get much better help, and maybe even find the answer yourself, if you take the time to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If you do have to post a question, make sure to post the *entire* code, not just the part that you think is important.  Also say exactly what inputs you are giving to the program (if any), what the actual output is, and what the expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your questions are stored in 'column' 0,

Change:

```
cout << "Question " << questionNum << ": " << testArr[row][col] << endl;
```

To:

```
cout << "Question " << questionNum << ": " << testArr[row][0] << endl;
```

after the first iteration through the loop printing out the questions, the variable `col` is left with the value `ARRAY_COL`, which isn't correct for printing out the next question.